# How to get value from alert Dialog box and set into a button in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a Page, having a button. On click of this button alert dialog opens which has a list inside of it.
On tapping one of the list item, the alert dialog closes and the main page is there. Just as the dialog is closed, I want to set the selected item value into the button.
For this, this button widget should be rebuild, but I am unable to do so. How to achieve this functionality.

On my page, I'm calling this mainData() which makes a button widget on the screen.

```
 Widget mainData() {
    return  RaisedButton(
      child: Text('$tempVal'),
      onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context){
              return AlertDialog(
                content: StatefulBuilder(builder:
                    (BuildContext context,
                    StateSetter setState) {
                  _setState = setState;
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: //
                        // new SearchBar(mainData: mainData, list: list,),
                        list.length > 0 
                            ? ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: list.length,
                          shrinkWrap: false,
                          itemBuilder: (item, i){
                            return Card(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Ink(
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                         tempVal = list[i].code;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        title: Text(list[i].value),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ) 
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
                ),
              );
            }
        );
      },
    );
    }
```

How do I refresh the button widget after I have gotten the value from the list?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the ontap method inside the listTile instead of the inkwell

```
ListTile(onTap: (){},title...
```

Comment: Tried. It had no effect.

Comment: try to print something inside the ontap method and check if the function is getting called.